# How to query whether a target is an INTERFACE library in CMake

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

In modern CMake one can specify a library as `INTERFACE`: it does not produce build output, but it can have properties associated to it, although not all properties can be set (for instance the `FOLDER` property is not supported). Say I have a generic CMake macro setting properties for a generic library target, is there a way to tell that the input target is an interface library, so that I can skip the unsupported properties only for that target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You query the [TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/TYPE.html) property of target....

```
get_target_property(type target TYPE)
if (${type} STREQUAL "INTERFACE_LIBRARY")
```